# How to declare enums in C#

Tags: c#, enums, declaration

I don't really get how to declare an enum, I tried this

```
enum cardValue {2 = 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K, A};
```

and

```
enum cardValue {"2" = 0, "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
```

And in both cases, the compiler complains about the notation I used. I know the format isn't right, but can I do something about that so the following code gets to work?
(Here, V could be `"K"`, `"5"`, or any of the other values)

```
struct card
{
    cardValue value;
    cardSuit suit;

    public card(string V, string S)
    {
        value = SomeTransformation(V);
        suit = SomeTransformation(S);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [C# Enum](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: Why don't you try looking at the msdn documentation?

Comment: Do you want to know how to implement `SomeTransformation`? You cannot create a method that returns two different types. So you need a `SomeCardValueTransformation` and a `SomeCardSuitTransformation`. You could check if the string contains only a digit, f.e. by using `int.TryParse`, then call the correct conversion method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum values should be from the same type. So your second example almost works. If you are using flags, you should give all the values an name or index, not just one:

```
enum cardValue { Val2 = "2", Val3 = "3", Val4 = "4", ValA = "A" };
```

Also, variable names, class names, enum values, etc. can't contain only numerics. So there has to be a character in the name.

Comment: `enum` _values_ must be integers (`int` by default, with the following types also permitted, but not recommended `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`),  so I don't think this will work

Answer (score 1):

enums can's have chars, default is int

The char type is classified as an integral type, but it differs from the other integral types in two ways:

• There are no implicit conversions from other types to the char type. In particular, even though the sbyte, byte, and ushort types have ranges of values that are fully representable using the char type, implicit conversions from sbyte, byte, or ushort to char do not exist.

• Constants of the char type must be written as character-literals or as integer-literals in combination with a cast to type char. For example, (char)10 is the same as '\x000A'.